# Count if a character appears three times or more in a string

Tags: python, string

I need to determine if a string has 3 or more `z`'s in it and return 1 if it does, and 0 otherwise.

For example:

```
print punk('abc')
# should return 0
print punk('laz zzzz')
# should return 1
```

My attempt:

```
def punk(s):
    lett=('z')
    for s in lett:
        if len(s)>=3:
            return 1
        else:
            if len(s)<=3:
                return 0
```

This only returns 0, no matter how many z's I have as an input. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Given that `for s in lett` makes `s` one character at a time (or an empty string if `lett` is an empty string), how could `len(s)` **ever** be anything other than `0` or `1`?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use built in functions you could try something like this:

```
def punk(s):
    count = 0
    for letter in s:
        if letter == "z" or letter == "Z":
            count += 1
    if count >= 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: *"Yes, but I shouldn't use built-in functions :/"*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even think about `sum` or `lower`. They are so common functions I somethings don't think of them as functions. :)

Comment: Don't write the code for him.  This is obviously homework.

Comment: @zondo: so? It's fine to ask questions about homework on SO.

Comment: @vaultah: Questions can be answered, but new code should not be written.  He can point out what is wrong with the code and say how to fix it, but he is re-writing the function.  The OP shouldn't pass the test just because MarkyPython gave him the answer.

Comment: @zondo, Why should we care? The OP is only hurting himself by asking other people to do homework for him.

Comment: @jsve: And MarkyPython helps him hurt himself.  What a laudable thing to do.

Comment: @zondo Unlike some new users, the OP has at least tried to create the code himself. Yes you are probably right it is a homework type question, and he should be able to work it out if he spends some more time on it. But he did ask a question that showed his intentions, what he tried, and what his output was. So I think it is an okay, not good, but okay question on SO.

Comment: I have no problem with the question, but he asked what was wrong with his code, not what code he should use.  When you show him a perfectly good function that he can use instead, you are practically forcing him to cheat.  You should merely point out the problem, and let him fix it himself.

Answer (score 3):

```
def punk(s):
    counter = 0
    for char in s:  # iterate over each character in s
        if char == 'z':            
            counter += 1
    return int(counter >= 3)   # int(False) => 0, int(True) => 1
```

You can use the built-in [`string.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) like this:

```
def punk(s): 
    return int(s.count('z') >= 3)
```

It's also possible to implement this using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) like this:

```
int(reduce(lambda x,y: x+int(y=='z'), a, 0) >= 3)
```

Comment: Then you have to cast it to an `int`.

Comment: Yes, but I shouldn't use built-in functions  :/

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate through every char in the string that gets passed in, not through every item in `lett`.

```
def punk(string):
    letters = ('Z', 'z')
    zCount = 0
    for char in string:
        if char in letters:
            zCount += 1

    return 1 if zCount >= 3 else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are testing `len(s)`, but `s` is defined because you say `for s in lett:`.  Therefore, the length of `s` will always be one.  Also, when you say `for s in lett:`, you are redefining `s`, so your original parameter is completely overridden.  Instead, you could create a counter and use a `for` loop with `for c in lett:`.  You could then add one to the counter every time `c` is `'z'`.  I won't write it out for you because that forces you to cheat, but that is one way to do it.